# Voltage monitoring Circuit

Tags: analog, circuit-design

I am trying to build simple voltage monitoring relay.I have ckt that goes to micro-controller pin. can some one suggest me ckt where i can power MC with isolated gnd. i would like to add L78M05 regulator drive from any one of phase.
weather it safe?
i dont prefer to use transformer based power supply.
I have seen some of design using capacitor and Resistor Network weather it has protection???

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQmQ5z.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: What voltage levels are these? I assume they are AC? What voltage can the microcontroller read?

Comment: These are 230VAC signal. output is 0-5V TO ADC MCU. I am looking for Power Supply not ckt for Voltage monitoring. I need transformerless  power supply where one phase used to drive 7805 or regulator IC 5V 0.5A.

Comment: What is ckt??? And what weather? It is totally unintellegible, what your setup is, what your problem is or what you want to acchieve. I recommend you get some help with your English to make your question more readable.